# Скрыть рамку у изображения

Tags: android, imageview

Изображение загружается из сети. Формат JPEG. По краям у изображения рамка в 1px. Как можно ее скрыть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему еще более радикальное, чем в самом первом ответе. У picasso android librtary есть метод:

> RequestCreator.transform(Transformation transformation)

Имплементируем интерфейс Transformation и его метод Bitmap transform(Bitmap source):

```
 @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            Bitmap bitmap = source.copy(source.getConfig(),true);

            //bitmap.recycle();
            Log.d("Test","h = "+bitmap.getHeight()+" w= "+bitmap.getWidth());
            for(int i = 0;i<(source.getWidth());i++){
                for (int j=0;j<(source.getHeight());j++){
                        if (i == 0 || j == 0
                                || i == (source.getWidth()-1) || j == (source.getHeight()-1)){
                            bitmap.setPixel(i,j, Color.WHITE);
                        } else {
                            bitmap.setPixel(i,j,source.getPixel(i,j));
                        }
                }
            }
            source.recycle();
            return bitmap;
        }
```

И используем к примеру так:
CropSquareTransformation transformator = new CropSquareTransformation();

```
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(getContext()
                .getString(R.string.image_hotel_request_url)+hotel.getImage())
                .transform(transformator)
                .into(photo);
```

Насчет скорости не уверен, все же побитовая обработка изображения, но результата добился - удаляю красную рамку шириной в один пиксель вдоль изображения.

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб. Думаю если вы картинку вставляете через `srс`, то как `Background` можно сделать так, и поменять цвет на цвет фона.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
   <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@android:color/white" /> //поменять на цвет фона
</shape>
```

Comment: Ну так то я закачиваю с помощью Picasso. Но сейчас попробую этот вариант